# Unversion in Tortoise SVN but not by extension

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is it possible, and how, to unversion the files by the name pattern often found among the SSRS reports: `*-Backup.rdl`?

Comment: Do you want to avoid them being checked in or do you already have them checked in?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

For individual files or very basic file name patterns you can right-click one of the files and then select `TortoiseSVN -> Add to ignore list -> (desired pattern)`.

[image: TortoiseSVN -> Add to ignore list -> (desired pattern)]

This will add the desired pattern to the svn ignore list. However from your question it seems like you would like to use a pattern which is not suggested from the beginning.

To do that you would need to add the correct svn property yourself. Right-Click on the folder where you have your files and select `TortoiseSVN -> Properties`. In the properties window, select New -> Other (or double-click the property `svn:ignore` if it already exists). Select `svn:ignore` and add your own file name pattern there. If you want multiple file patterns to be ignored they should be added on separate lines. Optionally you can add the property recursively (once to each subdirectory as well which may make it hard to maintain), but also see my point about global ignores below.

[image: svn:ignore]

Click ok and if all went well your properties should look something like this.

[image: TortoiseSVN properties]

On another note, you can also use a global ignore for your entire repository. To do that you would do the same procedure as I described above, but instead use the property called `svn:global-ignores`. This would just set the property once but it would have effect on anything further down the directory tree and will also work with any other global ignore setting further up the tree. The support for `global-ignores` is available starting with Subversion 1.8.

Also note that if you already have checked in a file with a matching pattern, that file will still be considered to be versioned and will be handled by Subversion as such. Adding ignores only ignores files to be considered to be added to the versioning system.

Comment: Adding a pattern to the property is complete, but the icons are still the same. I'll give it some time and check again later.

Comment: Few hours later still no change, the icons still showing `(?)` and `add to ignore list` is still active. I used `*-Backup*.rdl` pattern.

Comment: Changes should be instant. Just to double-check (didn't put that in my answer) did you commit the changes to the ignore list? You do that by comitting changes on the directory itself.

Comment: I will not have a chance to commit the entire folder for a long time. Previously when I used popup menu to add individual extension to an ignore list it was instant.

Comment: You don't need to commit the etire folder, meaning you can commit the folder itself but you don't need to commit any of the content in it. In the dialog where you select what to commit, only select the main folder, nothing else.

Comment: Committed just the directory. Still not ignoring those patterns.

Comment: Just did a test and it works fine for me. And I got to admit that it worked even without committing so I am not sure what goes wrong in your setup (I used the pattern you have specified). I have one of the newer TortoiseSVN clients but the svn server version is quite old so it shouldn't be that either. Icons have a tendency to stick in the Windows explorer, but when you commit the folder, the dialog should not list the files matching the pattern as non-versioned. Can you give me some example of full file names? Do you have your files in sub-folders of the folder you specified the pattern in?

Comment: Also: Did you use svn:ignore or svn:global-ignores?